# Delete element in MongoDB collection by index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and I have a users collection . A user instance is like :

```
    user = {"Email":"user@gmail.com" , "Comments":["Good"  , "Bad" , " Very bad "] }
```

I'm trying to delete elements in the Comments[] field by index (ex. index = 0 delete "Good")
I set the comment whose index is same as input number to "deleted" and then I pull it
However, since I am iterating over the Comments[] array for a specific user I get the error

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot create field 'i+1' in element
```

which I don't understand why .
My code :

```
                comment_num = int(comment_num) #an index I have as input
                exists = False #we will check if index exists in list 
                for i , value in enumerate(usr['Comments']):
                    if i+1 == comment_num: #if index is comment_num
                        print("Comment number exists")
                        exists = True
                        #I get the error here
                        users.update_one({"Email":email} , {"$set" : {"Comments.i+1" : "deleted" } } )
                        users.update_one({"Email":email} , {"$pull":{"Comments":"deleted" }})
                    elif i+1 == len(usr['Comments']) and exists == False:
                        print('Comment does not exist') #if index not found
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this error. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As of MongoDB v4.2 you can't use `$set` to directly target an array at a given index, you can't use `$pull` to remove an element at a given index either.

What you can do, starting from v4.2, is using the [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#updateone-behavior-aggregation-pipeline) to update your array as a concatenation of array elements before and after the specified index.

So if you have `i = 0` then it will be a concatenation of `[]` and `["Bad" , " Very bad "]`

if you have `i = 1` then it will be a concatenation of `["Good"]` and `[" Very bad "]`

We can use [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

```
users.update_one(
  { "Email": email } , 
  [{ // specify update as an array to use the pipeline update
    "$set": {
      "Comments": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          { "$slice": ["$Comments", i] }, // keep i elements from the start of the array
          { "$slice": ["$Comments", i+1, { "$size": "$Comments" } ] } // keep element from i+1 to the end of the array
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

TIP: if you want to remove the *first* or the *last* array element, you can use [`$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/index.html)

Comment: Yeah but how can I return my array to it's normal state after the deletion ?

Comment: You mean you want to get the deleted element back?

Comment: No , my array format to it's normal state . ex . "Comments" : ["good" , "bad"] instead of "Comments": "concatArrays":[...]

Comment: It should be in the same format, only one array element removed

Comment: Oh I see . Thank you for your answer when I have time I will test it

Comment: `$concatArrays` is an operator to combine arrays

Comment: I got 
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'

Comment: Then you probably have an older version of pymongo and/or mongdb

Answer (score 0):

FIXED : Way easier than I thought and less complicated .

```
            comment_num = int(comment_num)
            exists = False
            for i , value in enumerate(usr['Comments']):
                if i+1 == comment_num:
                    print("Comment number exists")
                    exists = True
                    users.update_one({"Email":email} , 
                    {"$pull":{"Comments":value}})
                elif i+1 == len(usr['Comments']) and exists == False:
                    print('Comment does not exist')
```

Comment: Your solution does not account for duplicate values. It might work for your use case but not a general one. What if you have ["Good", "Bad", "Very Bad", "Good"] and want to remove "Good" at index 3?

Comment: @thammada.ts I wanted it exactly for specific values

Comment: So if the same value occurs twice, do you want to remove both elements as well? In that case, you can just use `$pullAll`

Comment: @thammada.ts No I have a comments list with my comments numbered from 1 to .. last comment and I enter a number as input . Then the comment corresponding to the number gets deleted

Comment: OK, you mean still mean at the specific index. Your current solution does not account for that and will remove the first element that contains the same value

Comment: @thammada.ts You mean if 2 comments are the same it will delete the first and not the one corresponding to index ? If that is the case I can just change pull with $pullAll  as I see here

Comment: If you change to `$pullAll`, it will remove *all* comments matching the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216377/discussion-between-vasilis-skentos-and-thammada-ts).